# Why does error 0xe0434352 occur when calling a COM method in Delphi?

Tags: c#, delphi, asynchronous, com

When I add a COM reference in Visual Studio, this method works, but not with
Activator.CreateInstance(TypeZVT) or CreateOleObject in Delphi ...

Delphi:

```
 VarObj := CreateOleObject( 'Portalum_Zvt.ZVT' );
 VarObj.BetragSenden('1,22'); //Throws errors.
```

C# DLL:

```
private async void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    await PaymentAsync((decimal)Betrag);
}

public double Betrag;

public void BetragSenden(double Betrag)
{
    this.Betrag = Betrag;
    System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
    t.AutoReset = false;
    t.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
    t.Start();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `VarObj.BetragSenden(1.22)`?

Comment: Also get the error message with this.

Comment: 0xE0434352 is "MANAGED_EXCEPTION_CODE_V4". It just means somewhere along in your execution path,  a .NET code has thrown an exception - like throw new BlahBlahException(...) - and this becomes 0xE0434352 in other non-.NET languages. Proper debugging should show what's the real original exception.